# Remove unnecessary files from node_modules packages

Tags: npm

I would explain my question with an example.

when  i install a package like bootstrap in my project. the only files that are necessary and usable for me is in **/dist** folder and other file and folder are unnecessary.

```
------------ necessary - number of files: 20
<DIR>          dist
------------ unnecessary -number of files: 132
<DIR>          js
<DIR>          scss
         1,153 LICENSE
        10,973 package.json
        11,952 README.md
```

when i check other packages like **jquery** and **momment.js** and there was a lot of unnecessary files and folders and these files are several times more than needed files.

there is any way to remove these files or avoid installing these files?

thanks.